# replace a string, but ignore the ones that are between quotes (command line)

Tags: command-line, find-and-replace

I am trying to replace a string in a text in a file, with a hexvalue with gsar, but I am in doubt if gsar can fix this :)

Original text:

print "this is a print" "print" "*:;PRINT'" PRINT " PRINT" " print " PrInT

After "gsar" did its thing it should be:

XXXX "this is a print" "print" "*:;PRINT'" XXXX " PRINT" " print " XXXX

(XXXX represents the hex value a5)

I only want the word 'print' (case insensitive) replaced with the hex value a5, but only if it is not between quotes.
Also, please note that the quotes are the same hexidecimal value in the source file! (0x22)

The code: gsar -s"print" -r:x22 -o file.txt replaces of course also the words that are between quotes and it doesnt replace the words that are not the same case.

Is this even possible? :)
I would be very happy if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For such replacement, it's better to match what we want to keep (i.e. the values between quotes) and assert that the failled then match the rest.
This can be done with the verbs `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\w+`
- Replace with: `XXXX`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           # double quote
[^"]+       # 1 or more non double quote
"           # double quote
(*SKIP)     # skip what was matched
(*FAIL)     # and consider the match failled
  |           # OR
\w+         # 1 or more word character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for a solution. I want to use the result in a command line way (Windows). 
Do you have any idea what program could do that?

I tried Grep, but with your regex-string, I get errors. (by the way...what tool are you using?)

Comment: Here I'm using Notepad++ editor, it will also work with SublimeText. Not sure for grep but may be with `-P` option (Perl regex)

Comment: I cannot find a command line tool that can search and replace what I want. 
Can anyone help?