# Gsar expert needed (search and replace, command line only)

Tags: command-line, search, find-and-replace

I want to change a certain word in a file/on a line with a hex-value, with the use of `gsar.exe` (command line!), but ignore it if the word is somewhere between quotes

Original text:

```
9023 AAAA "this is a AAAA" "AAAA" "*:;AAAA'" Aaaa " Because AAAA" " aaaa " AaAa
```

text after gsar is done:

```
9023 XXXX "this is a AAAA" "AAAA" "*:;AAAA'" XXXX " Because AAAA" " aaaa " XXXX
```

(where XXXX represents the hex value a5)

Please note:

- it should be case insensitive
- it should ignore everything between quotes
- I want to use gsar.exe but sed.exe (Windows) or another command line tool would be good as well
- The opening quotes are the same as the closing quotes (0x22)

I have been working on this for a whole day now and I am not even close :P

A smart guy told me to use REGEX, and use the SKIP and FAIL method, so that "[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\w+ could be used as a way to select text that is not between quotes. This works great in the Notepad++ GUI, but I could not get that regex string combined with gsar for Windows.

I know this be done and probably with only 1 line. This is what makes it extra frustrating.
It doesn't have to be gsar. Sed.exe or another command line tool would be good as well!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace a string, but ignore the ones that are between quotes (command line)](https://superuser.com/questions/1730575/replace-a-string-but-ignore-the-ones-that-are-between-quotes-command-line)

Comment: No, it is not a command line solution. I need a command line solution.